# Calling a function like declaring a variable

Tags: c++, c, function

I just saw something similar to this in some code, and I was surprised that it compiles, could anyone tell me if this has a name?

```
bool value()
{
    return true;    
}

int main()
{
   bool value(); //why does this work? What is it?
   return 0;
}
```

My brain is telling me that it is some kind of making room in memory for the function, but at the same time is a function call... Okay, it really makes no sense to me.

Comment: It's not a call, as you'd see if the function output something. In fact, a compiler [could tell you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6fe18b05aeb7495) what it is.

Comment: Worth mention that it doesn't actually generate any code or do anything at run-time.  This sort of thing's mainly useful if the `value` function was defined after `main()` in the source file, but `main` needed to know its prototype so it could call it.  Not good practice IMHO... just keep `value` defined where it is and remove the `bool value();` line from `main()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a declaration of the function `value()`.

Normally we don't put it inside the function, but it's syntactically legal. Remember that functions can be defined once, but can be declared multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, I was so startled because I don't usually see functions being declared inside other functions, and thought for a second that it was doing something crazy.